# How do you override the warning "filename is not commonly downloaded" for a specific file?

Tags: google-chrome

There is a specific file on a customers server which I require to connect to one of their services. The contents of the file are confidential and the file is not intended for the public.

Thus, the file is not "commonly downloaded", and every time I need to download it, I get this warning:

[image]

I have to download that files sometimes multiple times a day (the contents of the file change periodically) and, every time, I have to click through this little annoyance.

The [Phishing and malware detection](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99020&p=ib_download_scan) page only explains how to disable the feature completely, which is not what I want at all.

Can I disable this feature for a single given URL?

Comment: You could write a macro/automation-script to automatically detect the URL in the Omnibar and click the button. That’s what I did a while back when I was writing a Chrome extension and got tired of constantly having to click several times in different places to get it to install every time I made a change and wanted to test.

Comment: @Synetech: Nice idea. Thanks :) Though, for my own download, I'm currently simply using a `.cmd` that uses `wget` to download the file when I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I couldn't find a way to resolve this properly in Chrome, I decided to resolve it outside of Chrome.

Given that I wanted to whitelist one specific file, I can also deal with this one specific download in a different manner.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\SU"
wget --no-check-certificate --output-document=connect.bat --user=oliver --password=secret https://vpn.secret.gov/connect.bat
connect.bat
PAUSE
```

Now I just pinned that to my Start menu and everything is better than it ever was.

Answer (score 1):

There's no client-side fix for this at the moment. There are some suggestions here for the server side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606586/downloading-exe-files-from-database

Comment: Yeah, I've come across that question, but it's not applicable in my situation.